# Compare variation products price before and after updating

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a variable product in woocommerce. I want to update its price but I have to have previous and new price for comparision. woocommerce has many hooks like

```
woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object
woocommerce_before_save_product_variation
```

but none of them give the previous price. All give the new price. It is possible to change core files of woocommerce but it's not recommended.

Is there any way to get previous price?

Appreciate any response

I used These hooks:

```
woocommerce_update_product_variation
woocommerce_before_save_product_variation
wp_ajax_woocommerce_remove_variations
woocommerce_save_product_variation
```

Comment: You can add the price as custom metadata when saving a product, so this way you can compare the updated product price with the previous price before saving…

Comment: You can get old price using woocommerce_before_product_object_save hook

Comment: I used both of theme. It works for simple products. But not working for variable products.